# How to pass headers in HttpTarget while using PACT

Tags: java, http-headers, pact

This the response provide by the API in body:

> "Please provide the valid App Id and SystemId in Header.",

This is my Code for provider:

```
@RunWith(PactRunner.class)
@Provider("questionnaire-services")
@PactFolder("target/pacts")
public class ProviderTest {
    
@TestTarget
public final Target target = new HttpTarget("http", "host", 8080, "path");

    @State("GET request")
    public void toGetState() { }
}
```

How do I pass headers in this `HttpTarget` method?